# Check for line in text bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, sed, grep

This is a really stupid question but I can't find an answer anywhere. So I have a command that prints out lines of text like this:

```
htop
kvantum
alacritty
```

And I need to check for a line, not a substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anchors... for example:

```
grep '^kvantum$' ...
```

Comment: With GNU grep, there's also the `-x` / `--line-regexp` option which is *"like parenthesizing the pattern and then surrounding it with `^` and `$`"*

Answer (score 1):

Bot `sed` and `grep` utilize regular expressions. If you want to match *a plain text string* `awk` can be a good alternative.

`$0` in awk is *entire line* - or more precise *record* separated by `RS` which defaults to newline.

```c
awk '$0 == "some line with $ and * and ..."' file
```

Or by variable:

```c
awk -v find='some line with $ and * and ...' '$0 == find' file
```